# Google Refine: Regular expression not working

Tags: regex, google-refine

I need to match a regular expression for a text facade in google refine. I tried the expression and it didn't work. Then I tried a simple case of matching string lenovo in www.lenovo.com using

```
value.match(/lenovo/)
```

in some of the rows my value takes value `www.lenovo.com` ,

How come such a simple string match, not working in Google refine. I'm running on windows.

Please let me know if I'm doing any obvious syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

What are you getting back, and what do want to get back?

The return value of the match() function is either null for no-match or an array

The help tab says:

> match (string or regexp) returns: array of strings Returns an array of
>   the groups matching the given regular expression

For an input value of "lenovo",
this function:  `value.match( /lenovo/ )`
should return this value:  `[]`

Do you want to turn this into a True/False value for your facet, to test the presence/absence of that text string?  You could do something like this:

```
isNotNull( value.match( /lenovo/ ) )
```

Comment: I want to do exactly this: I have a URL: http://www.bing.com/search?q=lenovo+outlet&form=MSNH14&qs=AS&sk=AS2&pq=lenovo&sp=3&sc=8-6 , I want to extract value of q parameter from url.

Comment: That's going a bit farther.  First, to extract a value, you need to use parenthesis to do a regexp capture.  Also, if you want to turn the result (an array) into the array's contents, you pull out the value at index position zero [0].  With that in place, you just need to play with the regexp to pull everything following the "q=" up to any possibly next ampersand.  Here's one way that's working for me with sample data:    value.match( /.*search\?q=([^&]+).*/ )[0]

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a group in your regular expression, eg this:

```
 value.match(/lenovo/)
```

which results in:

```
 []
```

should be:

```
 value.match(/(lenovo)/)
```

which results in:

```
 ["lenovo"]
```

Which is probably more like what you want.  You can then index the array to retrieve the string value:

```
  value.match(/(lenovo)/)[0]
```